# Make arrays of all values between span tags

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are some span tags in website:

```
<span class="valuearea">Text</span>
```

I need to get all values between these tags and add them to array or list.
`driver.find_element_by_class_name("valuearea")` finds first span tag and assigns to variable this tag. (variable.text shows Text between first span tags).

So, How to make it for all variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python

```
results = []
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
for element in elements:
    results.append(element.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i needed. Also, results.append(element.text)

Comment: Just testing you ;)   Edited to remove that spurious 's'.

Answer (score 0):

in java

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> temp = driver.findElements(By.className("valuearea")) // a list of elements with classname="valuearea"

for (WebElement ele : temp){
    result.add(ele.getText());
}
```